No categories could be matched to saved symbols in library
I have a set of categories for multiple sets of data which I would like to have categorized into the same set of colors every time. The categories are marked by the same letters in the data.

I was using this example on how to set a data-defined color ramp to save time
I have the colors saved individually and as part of a style

The letters look the same as they do in the data with no accidental extra spaces or anything like that

According to the example, I should be able to do Categorized->Value->"Bait" and then Advanced->Match to Saved Symbols
Instead, it cannot find it

What am I missing?

One work-around has been to rearrange the colors in the color ramp to appear in the order the letters appear in the data. Still curious though about why symbol matching isn't working.
